# C compiler for mac?

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm, cc

I'm working through a text on linking, and wanted to work along with some examples in said text.

To better understand whats going on when I invoke the `gcc` driver, I was looking into doing all the compilation old-school by hand;

- preprocessing using `cpp`
- compiling with `cc1`
- assembling with `as`
- linking using `ld`

Unfortunately, on my Mac I don't seem to be able to reference `cc1`directly (no listing of `cc1` in `man`). What are my options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read some material about GCC internals. First the wikipage on [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection). Then, you could play with the [MELT probe](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/index.html#probe_id) (you may want a Linux system to use it).
Then read the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/). And the [GCC resource center](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/grc/)

Use `gcc -v -Wall` to compile, it will show what `cc1` is running (and `-Wall` is always useful). So try compiling with `gcc -v -Wall hello.c -o helloworld.bin`

<sup>the `cc1` program don't sit in your `PATH` or in `/usr/bin/` but -on my system- in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1`</sup>

The command `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` will tell you which `cc1` is used by *your* `gcc`. See [GCC debugging options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#) for more.

The preprocessing is now inside `cc1`.

The `gcc` program is just a driver, starting `cc1` (which does most of the compiling work), then `as`, `ld` etc...

The [MELT site](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt) contains some documentation, and some slides explaining GCC, which you could find interesting. MELT is a domain specific language to extend GCC.

See also the picture on http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/cc1-internals.svg and the below picture

[image: http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/gcc-MELT-inside.png]

<sup>picture from http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/gcc-MELT-inside.png, done by me, CC BY SA</sup>

The `cc1` is producing a `.s` assembly file; the `as` (started by `gcc`) is transforming it into `.o`. The `ld` linker (started by `gcc`) will produce a library or an executable.

PS. I have a Linux system, but things are very similar on MacOSX.

#### reference on linking

A good book about linking is [Levine's Linkers & loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.

PS. MELT is obsolete in 2021, but I am working on the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer and on [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) (which generates C++ code).

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I installed gcc-10 with brew on my macOS (Catalina).

While `cc1` is not directly accessible (via PATH), it can be found in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0
```

If you are lost, try `gcc -v` and from the verbose information you may find where your `cc1` is.