# what compiler should I use as case study for self studying compiler principles techniques

Tags: c, compiler-construction, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, lexical-analysis

I decided to start studying compiler theory but the problem is that I want a compiler for any language in order to track each of

- lexical analyzer output.
- syntax tree.
- intermediate representation.
- code generation.
- I dont care for optimization right now

I am aware of some questions similar to mine about clang and gcc and I understand that both of them make lexical and syntax analysing on the fly
I just want any compiler in any language as long as the compiler itself is  written in C and run on ubuntu x64

Comment: no I have no Idea what is lex and what is YACC but I heard about bison (it is parser code generator)

Comment: Maybe some internals of LLVM would help you, there is a recent book: _Getting Started with LLVM Core Libraries_

Comment: I believe that clang is part of LLVM
and clang allows only
-E  Run the preprocessor stage.

       -fsyntax-only
           Run the preprocessor, parser and type checking stages.

       -S  Run the previous stages as well as LLVM generation and optimization
           stages and target-specific code generation, producing an assembly
           file.

       -c  Run all of the above, plus the assembler, generating a target ".o"
           object file.
there is no lexical analyser step shown or AST

Comment: For practical reasons and in order to be able to focus also on a more modern languages and best practices I'd recommend to scratch the "_compiler itself is written in C_" requirement. As this way you eliminate wide range of interesting languages and their [bootstraping compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you have the right approach, if you are willing to learn about compilation techniques for C specifically. And C is not the best language to write a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) in (if you start from scratch, Ocaml is better suited for that task). BTW, recent [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) are coded in C++ (no more in C).

The C language now sort-of requires *optimization*, as I explained [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065), so skipping the optimization part is not very useful. Be aware that optimization passes form the majority and the most difficult part of real-world compilers.

The [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) parts of compiler are now well understood. And there are several code generator tools for them (`yacc` or `bison`, `lex` or `flex`, [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/)...). For several pragmatical [reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254707/40065), real compilers like GCC don't use these tools.

You could look into [tinycc](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git), [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/), or [8cc](https://github.com/rui314/8cc) if you want to look inside *non-optimizing* toy C compilers.

You could also look into the intermediate representations of real compiler, e.g. [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) for [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (BTW, try to compile with `gcc -fdump-tree-all -O2 -c` some simple C code with a few loops; you'll be surprized by the hundreds of dump files showing the many internal compiler representations from many passes). You'll learn a lot by customizing GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), and the [MELT documentation page](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html) contains several very useful references. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694745/841108) should also help and contains or references some pictures of GCC.

<sup>disclaimer: I am the main author of MELT</sup>

PS. There are very good reasons to [bootstrap compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29). So a compiler for a language other than C is unlikely to be coded in C (it is often coded for that language itself), since C is not a good programming language to write a compiler from scratch.

PPS. If you only know C -and no other programming languages-, I would suggest to learn some other programming language (e.g. Scheme with [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), Ocaml, or Haskell or Scala or Clojure or Common Lisp) before diving into compilers!  Read also something about [Programming Language Pragmatics](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/). If you know a bit of Scheme or Lisp, Queinnec's book [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) will teach you a big lot.

Comment: I meant to say that the compiler itself should be written in C but it can be any used to compile any code other than C

Comment: Why do you want the compiler to be written in C?

Comment: because it is the language i know the best

Comment: @AhmedAbdElMawgood That isn't much of a reason. If you are, or aspire to be, a compiler writer, the choice of language should be almost immaterial from that point of view. You should be completely comfortable choosing the best language for the job, and learning it as necessary.

Comment: Wow! This answer has greatly expanded since I upvoted. +1 again.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many places to start from to explore this territory. Many languages include a compilation capability or aspect such as *Lisp* and *Forth*.

To learn about a C compiler, there is a book about the LCC compiler which includes the source code for the compiler. There are also repositories of old C compilers at The Unix History Society archive (tuhs.org).

Still another angle you could take is to examine the language *False* (an ancestor of the more famous *Brainfuck*) which is designed to be implemented with very little code.

Another angle, which connects to your interest in complexity theory, is to learn about the Chomsky Hierarchy of languages and the associated abstract machines which can parse them. This will teach you why Lex and Yacc are separate tools and what each is good for (and how to do it yourself and not need them at all).

I am actually on the very same quest myself. I'm currently reading the old 1979 book *Anatomy of Lisp* which contains compiler code in, of course, Lisp. But this is ok, because I already have my own homebrewed [lisp interpreter](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/sexp.c) to execute it with.

Comment: For LISP, be sure to read [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) by C.Queinnec.

Comment: I've got it in my wish list, but when I'm shopping, I never want to cough up the 50USD. *Anatomy* was only 40, the other day.

Comment: If you read French fluently, the French original version is slightly cheaper. BTW, I think Queinnec's book is worth the 50US$, but it requires some basic computer science education and a little bit of familiarity with some Lisp.

Comment: That's a thought. I do read French, but my vocabulary is all from Moliere, Rostand, and Baudelaire. But, I may be ready, figuratively and financially, when I get through *Anatomy.* I also have SICP on the shelf, but I've put it down several times. There's something I find hard to read about it. dunno what. MIT envy, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

The [Tiger language](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/) has been designed by prof. Andrew Appel exactly on purpose to illustrate, step-by-step, a full compiler construct process.

You can google for 'tiger language' and read some online resource, there are also some questions/answers here on SO, but the better choice would be to get a copy of the book for the language you prefer, and implement the parts you're most interested into.