# Problems with compiled gcc .s Code when linking

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, linker

First time here, Im running Kali linux 64bits ,Im a linux rookie and a new to ASM aswell.... So I pulled a code in C ,the wich works perfectly fine..... here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char *message , server_reply[2000];

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 2000 );

//Connect to remote server
if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) <0)
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected\n");

//Send some data
message = "Hola!!!!\n\r\n";
if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("Data Send\n");

//Receive a reply from the server
if( recv(socket_desc, server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("recv failed");
}
puts("Reply received\n");
puts(server_reply);

return 0;
}
```

So ... I use gcc -S -o example.s example.c , to get the ASM code... wich is:

```
.file   "test.c"
.section    .rodata
.LC0:
.string "Could not create socket"
.LC1:
.string "127.0.0.1"
.LC2:
.string "connect error"
.LC3:
.string "Connected\n"
.align 8
.LC4:
.string "Hola!!  , \n\r\n"
.LC5:
.string "Send failed"
.LC6:
.string "Data Send\n"
.LC7:
.string "recv failed"
.LC8:
.string "Reply received\n"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
.LFB2:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
subq    $2048, %rsp
movl    %edi, -2036(%rbp)
movq    %rsi, -2048(%rbp)
movl    $0, %edx
movl    $1, %esi
movl    $2, %edi
call    socket
movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
cmpl    $-1, -4(%rbp)
jne .L2
movl    $.LC0, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
.L2:
movl    $.LC1, %edi
call    inet_addr
movl    %eax, -28(%rbp)
movw    $2, -32(%rbp)
movl    $2000, %edi
call    htons
movw    %ax, -30(%rbp)
leaq    -32(%rbp), %rcx
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
movl    $16, %edx
movq    %rcx, %rsi
movl    %eax, %edi
call    connect
testl   %eax, %eax
jns .L3
movl    $.LC2, %edi
call    puts
movl    $1, %eax
jmp .L7
.L3:
movl    $.LC3, %edi
call    puts
movq    $.LC4, -16(%rbp)
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    strlen
movq    %rax, %rdx
movq    -16(%rbp), %rsi
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
movl    $0, %ecx
movl    %eax, %edi
call    send
testq   %rax, %rax
jns .L5
movl    $.LC5, %edi
call    puts
movl    $1, %eax
jmp .L7
.L5:
movl    $.LC6, %edi
call    puts
leaq    -2032(%rbp), %rsi
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
movl    $0, %ecx
movl    $2000, %edx
movl    %eax, %edi
call    recv
testq   %rax, %rax
jns .L6
movl    $.LC7, %edi
call    puts
.L6:
movl    $.LC8, %edi
call    puts
leaq    -2032(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    puts
movl    $0, %eax
.L7:
leave
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2"
```

So after using as example.s -o example.o, I use ld example.o -o example, and thats where I get these following errors:

> ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
>   test.o: In function `main':
>   test.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to`socket'
>   test.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `printf'
>   test.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to`inet_addr'
>   test.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `htons'
>   test.c:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to`connect'
>   test.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `puts'
>   test.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to`puts'
>   test.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `strlen'
>   test.c:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to`send'
>   test.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `puts'
>   test.c:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to`puts'
>   test.c:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to `recv'
>   test.c:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to`puts'
>   test.c:(.text+0x117): undefined reference to `puts'
>   test.c:(.text+0x126): undefined reference to`puts'

it seems to me that gcc is not usingn correctly .start, global main, etc. but to be honest I wouldnt know how to fix it., if this is correct then why?

Any help Will be appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use `gcc`? Please edit your question to explain!  Notice that `gcc` can be used to assemble and to link stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
gcc -Wall -O -fverbose-asm -S example.c
gcc -c example.s -o example.o
gcc  example.o -o example
```

Comment: Actually, the first command might better be `gcc-5 -Wall -O -fverbose-asm -S example.c`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It might be nice to explain the difference, even if minimally.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The difference between using -fverbose-asm and not? You can see more on the official docs here, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html but this doesn't really describe the half of it ie it annotates the assembly file with the options passed to gcc, gcc version etc and adds variable names to the relevant lines in the assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the help.... When trying to use gcc-5 -Wall -O -fverbose-asm -S example.c; I get the following msg:bash: gcc-5: command not found

Comment: Change gcc-5 to gcc or some variation thereof

Comment: Big noob question..... does the  commands you gave me  replace ld and as, correct?.

Comment: @Kawaxi It depends what you want to do. You're original question seemed to be about compiling assembly files into an executable, now you're asking about ld etc. Please read the following http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ld example.o -o example` tries to link just `example.o` and nothing else. To get missing symbols you need to link much more (e.g. startup code, standard library, C runtime, etc). Try `gcc -v example.c` to see how the linker should be invoked.

Comment: I get a bunch of stuff I cant even understand, do you need me to copy it?.

Comment: @Kawaxi It might be helpful.

Comment: stdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --wi

Comment: th-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test -version -o /tmp/ccPw8xy3.s

Comment: GNU C (Debian 4.9.2-10) version 4.9.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
 version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.

Comment: GNU C (Debian 4.9.2-10) version 4.9.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
 compiled by GNU C version 4.9.2, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: dc5310582b2a0cacbb4cea323963a0c0
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccb3gIZF.o /tmp/ccPw8xy3.s
GNU assembler version 2.25 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.25

Comment: COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccJoUZri.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/

Comment: COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccJoUZri.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/

Comment: lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../.. /tmp/ccb3gIZF.o -lgcc --as-need

Comment: ed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

Answer (score 2):

The commands given in [Harry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877816/841108) are the good ones:

```
gcc -Wall -O -fverbose-asm -S example.c
gcc -c example.s -o example.o
gcc  example.o -o example
```

Basically, you should be aware that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) would link your code with :

- startup code like [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) (actually, that is *several* object files today)
- the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (`libc.so`) (which will do some [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call))
- the [`libgcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html) providing a few low level, processor specific, functions (e.g. 64 bits arithmetic on 32 bits machine); it has a permissive but [ad-hoc](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1.en.html) license.
- and you often need some [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) like [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html)
- the kernel would provide [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)

How all this is linked together is known by the `gcc`  command, which will start some `ld`. Replace `gcc` with `gcc -v`  in your compilation commands to understand what exactly is happening. If you want to issue your own `ld` command you should add the options providing what I have listed above. The errors you are getting are notably because of the lack of `crt0` & `libc`

BTW on Linux most C standard libraries (e.g. [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (and so is GCC), so you can study their source code.

Try also `gcc -dumpspecs` which describes [what](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) `gcc` knows about issuing various commands (notice that `gcc` is only a driving program; the real C compiler is some `cc1`). Read also the wikipage on [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection). Some slides and references on the [documentation of GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html) gives a lot more information. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694745/841108) and the picture there.

I strongly recommend to also **use `gcc` to assemble** (some assembler code of yours) **and to link** stuff (because you don't want to handle all the gory details mentioned above, plus some other ones I did not mention).

Comment: thank you very much for you time and effort.... does this line looks reasonable to you? ld -o test -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/lib/crt0.o /usr/lib/libc.o test.o -lc /usr/lib/crtn.o

like you mentioned before when trying to apply it says :ld: cannot find /usr/lib/crt0.o: No such file or directory
ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libc.o: No such file or directory

I updated the libraries but it didnt fixed the problem, you think I need to install them manually?....  Im doing all this to then apply an objectdump.

Comment: Why can't you use `gcc`? Please edit your question to explain

Comment: so... those commands there do the same as ld and as... correct?. I was available to use them and the made a objdump I just need to be sure.

Comment: Replace `gcc`  by `gcc -v`  to understand *exactly* what is really running

Answer (score 1):

This is an important part:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtbegin.o
-lgcc 
--as-needed -lgcc_s
--no-as-needed -lc -lgcc
--as-needed -lgcc_s
--no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/crtend.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

`crt1`, `crti`, `crtbegin` supply the startup code where the `_start` entry point is actually defined (later on the control is passed to your `main`), `stdio` is initialized, etc. Similarly `strand` and `crtn` handle the cleanup after `main` return. `lc` supplies the standard library (like `puts` and other missing symbols). `lgcc` and `lgcc_s` have the `gcc`-specific runtime support.

The bottomline is, you need all that to be linked in.